# 'NSObject' may not respond to -navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

Hi there I currently I have a warning on a line of code where I am trying to push a new view onto the screen.
Outline // my NSObject receives a code=1 from my server I have set up. Everything works fine the code comes through which then initializes an AlertView where I have set up an if statement to catch the button click of my AlertView message. When that button is pressed my application falls over.

I have declared my ViewController of the view I am trying to push in its header file and there are no errors just the warning when compiled.

this is my NSObject I have made

```
    /////.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface alerts : NSObject {

}

- (void)pleaseRegisterDevice;

@end


/////.m
#import "alerts.h"
#import "instaCode1_3AppDelegate.h"
#import "RegisterDeviceViewController.h"


@implementation alerts

//use this alert when phone falls out of sync
- (void)pleaseRegisterDevice {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Register Device"
                                                    message:@"click OK to register"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert autorelease];
    [alert show];

}


//Catch pleaseRegisterDevice method
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        NSLog(@"msg from alertView method");

        //open new wndow

        RegisterDeviceViewController *regViewController = [[RegisterDeviceViewController alloc] init];


        //Push it onto the top pf the navigation controller's stack
        **[[self navigationController] pushViewController:regViewController animated:YES];**



    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"was not able to push view");
    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I have bolded the line of code where I get the warning 'alerts' may not respond to -navigationController

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think an `NSObject` subclass has a `UINavigationController`...
You need to get a pointer to your app delegate's navigation controller like so

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:regViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I knew the problem was something to do with this but because of my obvious lack of experience I wasn't sure of the exact details. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

`navigationController` is a property defined on a [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). A `NSObject` does not have this method.

Comment: :) thanks, as I'm new to encapsulating my code like this, its probably only the second time I have worked with a NSObject.. and was not quite aware of the rules regarding this type of thing. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any instance member or method called navigationController, hence the warning.